# Command line tool to access Amazon Athena

Tags: jdbc, command-line, amazon-athena

I am looking for a command line tool to make queries to Amazon Athena.

It works with JDBC, using the driver `com.amazonaws.athena.jdbc.AthenaDriver`, but I haven't found any command line tool that works with it.

Comment: From the [documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/athena/faqs/): _Amazon Athena can be accessed via the AWS management console and a JDBC driver. You can programmatically run queries, add tables or partitions using the JDBC driver._  It looks like the management console or code using JDBC are the only options being listed.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thanks for the response. Yes, I read that in the documentation too, but I wondered it there is any "unofficial" way to query from command line.

Comment: Well you could always write a thin wrapper console program in Java.

Answer (score 8):

Expanding on previous answer from @MasonWinsauer.   Requires bash and jq.

```sh
    #!/bin/bash

    # Athena queries are fundamentally Asynchronous.  So we have to :
    # 1) Make the query, and tell Athena where in s3 to put the results (tell it the same place as the UI uses).
    # 2) Wait for the query to finish
    # 3) Pull down the results and un-wacky-Jsonify them.


    # run the query, use jq to capture the QueryExecutionId, and then capture that into bash variable
    queryExecutionId=$(
        aws athena start-query-execution \
        --query-string "SELECT Count(*) AS numBooks FROM books" \
        --query-execution-context "Database=demo_books" \
        --result-configuration "OutputLocation"="s3://whatever_is_in_the_athena_UI_settings" \
        --region us-east-1 | jq -r ".QueryExecutionId"
    )

    echo "queryExecutionId was ${queryExecutionId}"


    # Wait for the query to finish running.
    # This will wait for up to 60 seconds (30 * 2)
    for i in $(seq 1 30); do

        queryState=$(
            aws athena get-query-execution --query-execution-id "${queryExecutionId}"  --region us-east-1 | jq -r ".QueryExecution.Status.State"
        );

        if [[ "${queryState}" == "SUCCEEDED" ]]; then
            break;
        fi;

        echo "  Awaiting queryExecutionId ${queryExecutionId} - state was ${queryState}"

        if [[ "${queryState}" == "FAILED" ]]; then
            # exit with "bad" error code
            exit 1;
        fi;

        sleep 2
    done


    # Get the results.
    aws athena get-query-results \
        --query-execution-id "${queryExecutionId}" \
        --region us-east-1 > numberOfBooks_wacky.json

    # Todo un-wacky the json with jq or something
    # cat numberOfBooks_wacky.json | jq -r ".ResultSet.Rows[] | .Data[0].VarCharValue"
```

Comment: To format 'get-query-results' as a table that should work:
`aws athena get-query-results --query-execution-id $QUERY_ID | jq -r '.ResultSet.Rows[].Data | map_values(.VarCharValue) | join(" ")' | column -tx`

Answer (score 4):

As of version 1.11.89, the [AWS command line tool](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli) supports Amazon Athena operations.

First, you will need to attach the AmazonAthenaFullAccess policy to the IAM role of the calling user.

Then, to get started querying, you will use the `start-query-execution` command as follows:

```
aws athena start-query-execution 
    --query-string "SELECT * FROM MyDb.MyTable" 
    --result-configuration "OutputLocation"="s3://MyBucket/logs" [Optional: EncryptionConfiguration]
    --region <region>
```

This will return a JSON object of the QueryExecutionId, which can be used to retrieve the query results using the following command:

```
aws athena get-query-results
    --query-execution-id <id>
    --region <region>
```

Which also returns a JSON object of the results and metadata.

More information can be found in the official [AWS Documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/athena/).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Adding to this, keep sleep  command after aws athena start-query-execution query as it is running the query at backend which takes time. So, in shell script , set the value of sleep accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

You can try AthenaCLI, which is a command line client for Athena service that can do auto-completion and syntax highlighting, and is a proud member of the dbcli community

https://github.com/dbcli/athenacli

Answer (score 0):

[athena-cli](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/athena/) should be a good start.